# Why did my valid question get closed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reopen-closed

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532543/hadoop-cluster-topologies) 
is my question. I did not find a valid answer on Google or Hadoop's official site.
But this question got closed. It is not fair things but moderators, I may not have your reputation points, but I am also an developer but just new in Hadoop.
If you guys have answers do let me know. Otherwise open my question.

Comment: I closed it for the reasons posted by [Nicol Bolas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116579/140951) and [slugster](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116572/140951) (vague, broad, asking for links); this simply doesn't make for good content on Stack Overflow and has been treated as such.  Remember, the idea is not just to help *you* but to help everyone who might have the same problem in the future.  That said, if you edit your question to a state where it *will* contribute value, please flag it and we can reconsider opening it (or post a new question, just make sure it's a quality question).

Answer (score 12):

Stack Overflow, and the other Stack Exchange sites, are not a magical answer box that you can shake at your whim to get information you want. We are not a replacement for or supplement to Google. We are not here to do research for you. We are not here to provide you with "links and examples".

SO exists to answer questions that have reasonable, definitive answers. Such questions must, by their very nature, be *specific*. A general question, "How do I do this" has many possible answers, most of which are different and equally valid. That is what is meant by "overly broad".

If you're absolutely new to something, then many if not most of your questions will not be appropriate for this site. Such persons don't need answers; they need *help*. They need guidance and hand-holding. And Stack Overflow is *not* a help desk or a tutorial.

In order to ask appropriate questions, you need to have at least some knowledge and/or have a *specific* problem. A specific problem is not "where do I start?" or "how do I implement this kind of system?" A specific problem is, "I can't get machine X to work in my hadoop cluster. I'm using [insert system here], with [insert other software here], and I've tried [insert things you've tried here]."

Comment: I think i have just asked what topologies are available in hadoop? Is that overly broad then what are other ways i can ask same question? And thanks for telling me whats stack overflow.And i am not at all asking anyone what to do?how to do? i just need general information or what error message means.Hoping stack overflow provide that.

Answer (score 10):

It seems reasonably clear (to me) what you are asking (not that I can answer it). However it does seem to fit the definition of *overly broad*, and quite possibly *vague*.

Basically, you may need to write several chapters in a book to answer your multi-part question. And just asking for links to other sites which discuss your topic doesn't make your question a high quality one. But even if you did refine it further, it would probably be off topic for Stack Overflow, and maybe a better fit on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: No, I would disagree that this would be a better fit on SU. SF, maybe, but not SU.